# 1D Unsteady Constant Area Duct Flow Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

For 1D constant area isentropic flow(assume inviscid and adiabatic). Given the following relations:
$$\rho = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} $$
$$\rho u = -\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} $$
where $a$ is the speed of sound and $u$ is the fluid speed.
Prove the following:

1. This equation (which is the governing equation) is satisfied:
   $$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \rho u}{\partial x} = 0  $$
2. This governing equation can be rewritten in the following way:
   $$ \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}+2u\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x \partial t}+ (u^2-a^2)\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} =0 $$
3. Finally, prove that 2) equation is "always" hyperbolic

My attempt:

1. First, I would appreciate it if someone elaborated what is it meant by the this equations being satisfied, what I did is I subbed in my relations into the governing equation and used the info that cross derivatives are equal or: $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t\partial x}$
   and got the following:
   $ \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x \partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t \partial x} $
2. For the second part, I subbed in for the relations and used product rule but I am still getting an incomplete expression so I am not sure what I am missing.
   and finally for 3) if I use the following to classify my PDE:
   $$ A_{2}^2 -4A_{1}A_{3} > 0 $$
   then PDE is Hyperbolic and what I found is this is equal to $4a^2$.
   Thanks for the help

Comment: "where a is the speed" : where is "a" ?

Comment: the speed of sound is not necessarily provided to us in the problem but can be defined as: $a^2 = (\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho})_{s} $